# IPython Notebook - Is it safe to delete temporary files and folders?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

IPython Notebook has been opening lots of temporary folders, including those ending with .ipynb[some random chars] and folders with checkpoints.
I guess some of them were created when my compyter crashed or all sort of things happened. I would have assumed those files would clean themselves once everything is normally saved, but they don't. They keep being there, trashing my workspace.

Is it safe to delete those files and folders, once I've saved my original .ipynb file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works like any other checkpoint-systems. They are always safe to delete, but you never know when you will need them, which is why they are created.

An interesting question could be how you can disable the whole checkpoint system.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to delete those files(.ipynb_checkpoints) after saving your progress to the main file

This files are there as a backup but you can delete it if it is cluttering your workspace